# EmguCV/ FFmpeg get video information

Tags: video, ffmpeg, emgucv

How to get information about a video file (ex: frames per second, bitrate, frame height, width etc) using emguCV or FFmpeg to a C# code. I am using C#.net for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe shiping ffmpeg's ffprobe.exe (from zeranoe builds) along with your project, running it silently and parse its output?

```
using System; using System.Diagnostics; using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace MyClientApp
{  public class MyApp
   {  public static void Main()
      {  var proc = new Process { StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo 
         {   FileName = "ffprobe.exe",         Arguments = "testvideo.mp4",
             UseShellExecute = false,          RedirectStandardError = true, CreateNoWindow = true }
         };    
         proc.Start();
         while (!proc.StandardError.EndOfStream) 
         {  string line = proc.StandardError.ReadLine();
            Match match = Regex.Match(line, @"Video:.*(\d{3,5}x\d{3,5}).*$");
            if (match.Success) 
               Console.WriteLine("resolution is: {0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
         }
      }
   }
}
```